# Update and fetch the latest data from scraped website on Heroku app

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, cheerio

I have made an API using Express.js and scraped a website using cheeriojs. I have deployed this API using heroku. I want my web application to fetch the latest data from the scraped website but my deployed app is not doing so. It is still showing the old data . How to make it fetch live data continuously

Comment: Provide more information. Code, logs, ... . Noone can provide a proper answer to an unproperly formulated question.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I got stuck in a similar problem.The way out was using cron jobs and the database simultaneously.
So I configured cron jobs to visit my website twice a day to activate the server(You don't need this if you have a good number of active users).
So  when the server restarts, my app checks if the data stored in my db(i.e. the last data that was scraped from the source when the server was active previously) is the same as the one that is currently present on the target website(from where I scrape data). If it is true then do nothing, else{
update the db with the latest data and display the same on your website
}
The drawbacks with this approach are:
1.It updates data only twice a day
2.If your site has many active users throughout the day, their constant visits won't let your app's server to get idle and hence at the time that you configure for the cron job to visit your site,there are chances that your server may already be online at that moment and it may not update the data.

However , for less active users this way works perfectly fine.
You can configure cron jobs from here: https://cron-job.org/en/members/jobs/